# Sign in button has no visible effect in a Java application

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, networking

I have two applications, one is a server and the other is a client. At first, I run my server application. Then I will run the client application. When running the client application, a window will be shown to prompt for a username and password and if they were correct, another window will be shown. When I click on the “Sign In” button, nothing happens. What's wrong?

Main class in Server application:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Server is starting...");

    ServerSocket server = null;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(5000);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.out.println("Server is listening...");
    while (true) {
        try {
            Socket socket = server.accept();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("Client Connected...");

    }
}
```

Client class which has a socket in it:

```
private static InformationClass info = new InformationClass();
private static Socket c;
static BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void runAClient() {
    try {
        c = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
public static void clienT(){
    try {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));
        while (true) {
            String string = reader.readLine();
            write.write(string, 0, string.length());
            write.newLine();

            write.flush();
            System.out.println(read.readLine());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}

public static boolean connected() {
    boolean bool = false;
    if (c.isConnected()) {
        info.setSituation("Connected");
        bool = true;
    } else {
        info.setSituation("disconnected");
        bool = false;
    }
    return bool;
}
```

The main window in the client application, which I start after when I run the server application. A part of that is for the “Sign In” button.

```
private void submit() {
    String id = idField.getText();
    char[] pass1 = passField.getPassword();
    String pass = new String(pass1);
    if (id.equals("") || pass.equals("")) {
        ErrorFrame frame = new ErrorFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        boolean b = Manager.Test(id, pass);
        if (b == true) {
            Main.runAClient();
            boolean boOl = Main.connected();
            if(boOl==true){
                this.setVisible(false);
                ListFrame fRAme = new ListFrame(client);
                fRAme.setVisible(true);
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "You couldn't connect successfully,please try again!","sign_In Problem",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "You have entered wrong datas,try it again");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked at the title, saw the `exclamation marks!` and said to myself: That must be Johanna! ;)

Comment: is the "this" used in the JOptionPane visible?

Comment: @ extraneon:yes,and "this" is that frame which has the sign in button.but I click on the button but it doesn't work well!

Comment: This isn't my homework!!

Comment: @Johanna: It may not be homework strictly speaking, but it does sound like "do-my-work-for-me". You aren't asking a programming question, you're asking people to debug your code. For all intents and purposes that's the same as "do my homework". The answer to this question will likely ever benefit only one person.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried stepping through your code using a debugger to work out precisely which line of code is not working correctly?  Simply stating that "nothing happens" when you click on the sign-in button doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: I debugged ,it goes well.when I run the server and then the client application:the sign in button will not work.BUT when i don't run the server(I just run the client application):the sign in button will work but the connectException will be thrown.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint on the ActionListener's actionPerformed(ActionEvent) method and stepping through from there.  Which line of code in the client do you get too?  Which path are you following through the submit() method?

Comment: I have cleaned these lines: if(boOl==true){this.setVisible(false)ListFrame fRAme = new ListFrame(client);
fRAme.setVisible(true);}
            else{
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "You couldn't connect successfully,please try again!","sign_In Problem",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;

            }

and I wrote these lines instead:ListFrame fRAme = new ListFrame(client);
                fRAme.setVisible(true);
 and the sign in button works well.BUT ,I have searched a lot that how can I handle the connectException but I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your submit() method is called when you click 'Sign In' button?
Another thing, Main.RunAClient() never returns constantly asking user to enter a line in system console.