# How can we handle the ConnectException?

Tags: java, networking

I have searched a lot ,but i couldn't find the fine answer for it.I use try_catch block for this exception(if this exception is thrown one frame will be shown to the user that I will tell him/her a message) but it still show the exception in the console.please help me.Thanks.

submit() method which will throw this exception:

```
  private void submit() throws ConnectException {

    String id = idField.getText();
    char[] pass1 = passField.getPassword();
    String pass = new String(pass1);
    if (id.equals("") || pass.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You should enter an ID and password", "Sign_In Problem", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        return;
    } else {
        boolean b = Manager.Test(id, pass);
        if (b == true) {
            this.setVisible(false);

            Main.runAClient();

            ListFrame frame = new ListFrame(client);
            frame.setVisible(true);





        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You have entered wrong datas,try it again", "Sign_In Problem", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I work with netbeans,this is an action for sign in button:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        submit();
    } catch (ConnectException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You coudn't connect to the server successfully,try it again", "Sign_In Problem", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);

    }}
```

my runAClient method:

```
 public static void runAClient()throws ConnectException{
    try {
        c = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
    } catch (ConnectException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

stacktrace:

```
init:
deps-jar:
compile-single:
run-single:
Jan 11, 2010 5:20:35 PM ClientNetWork.Main runAClient
SEVERE: null
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:518)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:468)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:365)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:179)
        at ClientNetWork.Main.runAClient(Main.java:29)
        at ClientGUI.MainFrame.submit(MainFrame.java:335)
        at ClientGUI.MainFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:233)
        at ClientGUI.MainFrame.access$400(MainFrame.java:34)
        at ClientGUI.MainFrame$5.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:122)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicRootPaneUI$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicRootPaneUI.java:191)
        at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1636)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2849)
        at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(KeyboardManager.java:267)
        at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(KeyboardManager.java:216)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(JComponent.java:2926)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2918)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2812)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5815)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1848)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:697)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:962)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:834)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:661)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4282)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Comment: after 105 questions, didn't you learn to give code samples ?

Comment: Please paste the full stacktrace from the console... perhaps it isn't throwing the exact exception that you think it is?

Comment: I was editing my post that you wrote this comment,any way ,sorry!

Comment: when i run the server application before the client application .it doesn't show this exception.BUT I want to handle this exception when the server application wont be run.

Comment: just in case - give the Main.RunAClient code

Comment: pff, classic.. laura found the code of your runAClass method in another question of yours where it seems that you are logging your exception there. 

Check http://bozhobg.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/tips-for-identifying-and-debugging-problems/ and don't ask questions which have obvious answers IF you look at your own code!

Comment: It would seem to me that there is an art to asking good questions which involves minimalism.  People who chunk 2 pages of code in their question usually don't know what's going on.  This is my experience as a lab tutor.  on the other hand that could be a good reason for asking a question :-p

Comment: Mehcko - right - posting all of your code doesn't make sense. People are in the developer profession, because they have analytical skills (or should have). So one should identify the piece of code which is causing the trouble and include only it.

Answer (score 7):

You posted the code in your previous question: [Sign in button has no visible effect in a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041817/gui-problemnetwork-problem)

Judging by the `runAClient` method, you are logging the exception and eating it up (not throwing it further).

```
public static void runAClient() {
    try {
        c = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The second catch (`IOException`) should not log and should throw the exception. Actually, you probably want to split that catch into a ConnectException catch which you would throw and a IOException catch which you can handle separately.

Edit: I'll extend this a bit. [`ConnectException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/ConnectException.html) extends [`RemoteException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/RemoteException.html) which in turn extends `IOException`, which you are catching and logging in your `runAClient` method. You can do two things:

- remove the `IOException` altogether, and catching it at an upper level (a solution which is very ugly in my opinion)

or

- split the `IOException` block into two catch blocks, one for the `ConnectException`, in which you just throw, and one for the rest of the `IOException`s, which you can log (or handle differently) - just make sure the `ConnectException` block is written before the `IOException` block

Comment: (+1), just be explicit about ConnectionException extending IOException, hence being caught.

Comment: @Johanna: What exactly are you asking?  Laura has shown how to restructure your code to not swallow the exception.  Are you asking why the exception is actually happening?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the code for

```
  Main.runAClient();
```

perhaps somebody is catching that exception and logging it, and then rethrowing?

Comment: Indeed it is being logged, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041817/gui-problemnetwork-problem